# Ionic 2 - Dynamically change the color of the Status Bar

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to change in a page in the ionic the status bar color depending on the parameter that is get.

Only the `colorStatusBar` variable inside the `onDeviceReady()` function appears as `undefined`.

Could someone help me with this problem?

```
typeColor: string;
colorStatusBar: string;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, statusBar: StatusBar){
    this.typeColor = this.navParams.get('type');
    if(this.typeColor == "value1"){
      this.colorStatusBar = "#F44336";
    }
    if(this.typeColor == "value2"){
      this.colorStatusBar = "#66BB6A";
    }
    if(this.typeColor == "value3"){
      this.colorStatusBar = "#9E9E9E";
    }

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
          console.log(this.colorStatusBar) // undefined
          statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(this.colorStatusBar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only make it work as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

...

typeColor: string;
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public platform: Platform){

        this.typeColor = this.navParams.get('type');
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            if(this.typeColor == "value1"){
                statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#F44336");
            }
            if(this.typeColor == "value2"){
                statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#66BB6A");
            }
            if(this.typeColor == "value3"){
                statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#9E9E9E");
            }
        })
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by moving your logic inside an `ionViewDidLoad()` (runs after the constructior) and using `platform.ready()` to ensure Cordova has booted up:

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.typeColor = this.navParams.get('type');

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        if(this.typeColor == "value1"){
            this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#F44336");
        }
        if(this.typeColor == "value2"){
            this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#66BB6A");
        }
        if(this.typeColor == "value3"){
            this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(#9E9E9E");
        }
    }
}
```

In which case your constructor changes to this:

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public statusBar: StatusBar, public platform: Platfom){
    // empty :), but notice the dependency injection of Platform
}
```

Don't forget to import `Platform` on the top:

```js
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
```

For your specific example to work, you need to make sure that you are invoking this present page from a parent page *and also* passing in the param `type`!

So in the parent page (you haven't shared the code for that) you need to have something like this:

```js
export class ParentPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  pushPage(){
    // push another page onto the navigation stack
    // causing the nav controller to transition to the new page
    // optional data can also be passed to the pushed page.
    this.navCtrl.push(MyStackOverflowSharedPage, {
      type: "value2"
    });
  }
}
```

For more info on that read the documentation on [`NavController`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: Inside the `this.platform.ready().then(() => {console.log(this.typeColor ) \\undefined` Variable remains `undefined`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question though (dynamically change the color of the Status Bar). This is an issue of pushing into this page (from another page) without passing in the `type` parameter. In any case I have edited my post with instructions on that as well.